# Please help explain the meaning of '\n' and '0';

Tags: arduino-uno

Please help explain the meaning of `'\n'` and `'0'` in the lines

```
if (isdigit(readValue) && readValue != '\n') 
{
  cellValue = cellValue * 10 + readValue - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '\n' in interpreted as a line-feed character.  It is one of many printable and non printable [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters computers use.  Usually, character strings are terminated using a line-feed.  So this line of code is likely testing for the end of a string of characters.

The '0' is interpreted as the ASCII value for the character which looks like the number zero.  Strange enough, when printing characters, the ASCII value for the charter which looks like the number zero actually has a value of 48.  And one has a value of 49.  Two a value of 50.  Three a value of 51. And so on.  So, to convert a number found in a character string into numbers like 0, 1, 2 & 3, programmers subtract 48 from the character.  Using '0' instead of 48 works as both represent the same value.  And, by subtracting '0', it is clearer to the seasoned programmer that a conversion from ASCII numbers to normal numbers is underway.

Answer (score 0):

\n stands for new line feed. It is one of the many "escape sequences" in C. Escape sequences start with "\" and it imply a predefined meaning to compiler.

Refer: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

In ASCII, decimal numbers from 0-9 are represented in 7-bits, in the range 48-57. So if a and b are integers, then:
b = a - '0' means  b = a - 48

Refer:
https://ascii.cl/index.htm?content=mobile